# DAX formula for - MAX of COUNT

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have the below dataset:

[image]

using the measure:

```
BalanceCount := COUNT(Balances[Balance])
```

which gives me the result:

[image]

However, I want the Grand Total to show the maximum amount of the BalanceCount, which is 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NewMeasure:=
MAXX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        FactTable
        ,FactTable[Account]
        ,FactTable[MonthEnd]
    )
    ,[BalanceCount]
)
```

SUMMARIZE() groups by the columns specified, and MAXX() iterates through the table specified, returning the maximum of the expression in the second argument evaluated for each row in its input table.

Since the filter context will limit the rows of the fact table, we'll only have the appropriate subsets in each column/row grand total.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for this particular case. It will not work if columns other than Account and MonthEnd are included in the filter context.

```
MaxBalanceCount:=
MAXX ( SUMMARIZE (
        Balances,
        Balances[Account],
        Balances[MonthEnd]
    ),
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Balances ) )
)
```

Comment: There is insufficent introspection capability in DAX to define a measure to group by the fields making up the filter context in a pivot table.